# How do I fix this issue with STRINGdb?

Tags: r

I am trying to go through STRINGdb tutorial since I believe it will be beneficial for my work.

```
library(STRINGdb)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new( version="11.5", species=9606, 
                           score_threshold=200, network_type="full", input_directory="")
data(diff_exp_example1)
example1_mapped <- string_db$map( diff_exp_example1, "gene", removeUnmappedRows = TRUE )
hits <- example1_mapped$STRING_id[1:200]
```

These lines of codes work perfectly fine, I created a data frame with their examples which included a gene name, Pvalue and logFC and STRING_id, Since the data frame was quite large I followed their example and picked only 200 genes but when I try to do their next step and create a plot from this data like this:

```
string_db$plot_network(hits)
```

I get this error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_NOT_TIME_VALID
```

I get the same error when I am trying to continue with their tutorial and work on something else. Unfortunately I cant fix it on my own.

Comment: Sounds like an issue connecting to their database. Could either be on their end (bad handshake), or on yours (firewall, IT security policy, etc.) that restricts your ability to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download latest ca-bundle.crt certificate from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Rename cacert.pem file and copy into user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/RCurl/etc

Comment: Thank you this fixed the problem for me, it now works as it should! Thank you again, I appreciate your help.